# Efficiently fill out (locf/nocb) values of data.table column, then aggregate by another column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with a column of customer IDs, a column of days on which they made a purchase, and a column with the value of that purchase. What I want to do is to compute the average of the purchase values on each day across customers, filling in missing values with the next available value.

For simplicity's sake, I'll have no duplicate days in my minimal example.

```
library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(custid=rep(seq(10),5), day=sample(50), val=rnorm(50,0,1))[order(custid,day)]
```

Now, I know how to solve this, but I don't know how to do it efficiently. One solution is to expand the data.table so that missing values become NA, and then to carry the next observation backward using `na.locf()` from `zoo`:

```
library(zoo)
res <- dat[as.data.table(expand.grid(custid=seq(10), day=seq(50))), on=c('custid','day'), allow.cartesian=TRUE, nomatch=NA][order(custid,day)]
res[, val:=na.locf(val, fromLast=TRUE, na.rm=FALSE), by='custid']
res <- res[,list(meanVal=mean(val, na.rm=TRUE)), by='day']
```

However, this creates a very large table when there are many days and many customers, but most customers only purchased on a handful of days. So I don't want that.

Another solution is to loop over the days, filter and aggregate per day, and then bind the rows into a data.table again:

```
res2 <- list()
for (dy in seq(max(dat$day))) {
    res2 <- c(res2, 
              list(dat[day>=dy, .SD[1], by='custid'][,list(day=dy, meanVal=mean(val, na.rm=T))]))
}
res2 <- rbindlist(res2)
```

However, this is slow.

Could anyone come up with a data.table solution that neither requires a slow loop, nor the creation of a large intermediate table?

Comment: Does `aggregate(dat, list(dat$day), mean)[, c('day', 'val')]` do what you want?

Comment: If you want to replace the NAs with the next value before averaging, you can do an assignment directly    `dat[is.na(dat$val), ]$val <- dat[which(is.na(dat$val)) + 1, ]$val`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my limited testing this is faster than either of your options (btw use `CJ` instead of `data.table(expand.grid`), and doesn't use much memory:

```
dat[dat, on = .(day >= day), mean(val[!duplicated(custid)]), by = .EACHI]
```

This assumes data is sorted by day as in OP.

Comment: That's what I was looking for - a pure data.table solution! Thanks!